# Writing and reading data to binary file using fstream

Tags: c++, file, binaryfiles, binary-data

I need to create a binary file and store inside it 10 numbers, and after that go one by one element of file and replace it with it's opposite number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main() {
  std::fstream file("numbers.dat", std::ios::app | std::ios::in|std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
  for (double i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), sizeof i);
  int length_of_file = file.tellg();
  int number_of_elements = length_of_file / sizeof(double);
  for (int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++) {
    double num;
    file.seekg(0); // change mode to reading
    file.seekg(i * sizeof (double));
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&num), sizeof num);
    num = num * -1;
    file.seekp(0); // change mode to writing
    file.seekp(i * sizeof (double));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&num), sizeof num);
  }
  // after change
  file.seekg(0, std::ios::end); // position cursor to the end
  length_of_file = file.tellg();
  number_of_elements = length_of_file / sizeof(double);
  for (int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++) {
    double num;
    file.seekg(i * sizeof (double));
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&num), sizeof num);
    std::cout << num << " ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10

If I don't use `std::ios::app` and make an empty file *numbers.dat* before running program, I would get correct output:

-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10

*std::ios::app* according to cpp reference means *seek to the end of stream before each write*

Is there any way to create a file with mode that would *seek to the beginning of stream before each write*?

Is there anyway to solve this without creating an empty file before running program?

- Note: It is not allowed to load file elements into an array or similar container data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mode is wrong in two ways. Firstly `std::ios::app | std::ios::binary` does not allow you to read from the file, and secondly it means that all writes will be at the end of the file irrespective of the current position.

The `-1` file position that you see means the `seekg` call has failed, presumably because you tried to read from a file you hadn't opened with `std::ios::in`.

You should use `std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary` although this requires the file to exist before you open it, or you could use `std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary`
but this will destroy any existing contents of the file.

BTW the repeated `seekg` and `seekp` aren't needed. You only need to set the position one time to change modes.

Comment: I edited my code just a second before you posted answer, thank you very much, I needed `std::ios::trunc` for this